# Customize the write operation in Mongo from Spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mongodb-query

How can I write to mongo using spark considering the following scenarios :

1. If the document is present, just update the matching fields with newer value and if the field is absent, add the new field. (The **replaceDocument** parameter if **false** will update the matching records but not add the new unmatched fields while if set to **true**, my old fields can get lost.)
2. I want to keep a datafield as READ-ONLY, example there are two fields, **first_load_date** and **updated_on**. first_load_date should never change, it is the day that record is created in mongo, and updated_on is when new fields are added or older ones replaced.
3. If document is absent, insert.

Main problem is replaceDocument = True will lead to loss of older fields not present in newer row, while False, will take care of matched but now the newer incoming fields.

I am using Mongo-Spark-Connector 2.4.1

```
df.write.format("mongo").mode("append").option("replaceDocument","true").option("database","db1").option("collection","my_collection").save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what you are trying to achieve here:
You can use something like :

```
(df
 .write
 .format("mongo")
 .mode("append")
 .option("ordered", "false")
 .option("replaceDocument", "false")
 .option("database", "db1")
 .option("collection", "my_collection")
 .save()
 )
```

replaceDocument set to `false` will help you in preserving your old records and updating the matched ones while the you can get a `BulkWriteException` for which the ordered parameter set to `false` will help.